HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized - Developer portal
I am creating oauth2 authorization server using flowing these steps in the link https://azure.github.io/apim-lab/apim-lab/7-security/security-7-2-3-oauth2-authorization-grant-flow.html.
I have created a backend app and registered a client app, Also have created oauth2 server in client app and configure API to use server.
I get error on developer portal

Has anyone faced this kind of issue? Is there something I am missing?


I have five backend apps and want to create only one oauth2 server for all backend apps.  I have added client app id into backend app's Expose an API -> Add Client application and in backend app ids in client app's API permissions -> Add a permissions. I have also added client app id in an audiences(APIM policy) in open api specs.
While creating oauth2 server I have tried given api://client-app-id/.default but it throws an error

{
"code":"Unauthorized","message":{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90009:
Application 'client-app-id' is requesting a token for itself. This
scenario is supported only if resource is specified using the GUID
based App Identifier. Trace ID: 794afd03-1bc0-47dc-aa7f-2ec71e9f2500
Correlation ID: 9c520cd6-f0a3-4b86-9c7a-14975246d845 Timestamp:
2024-08-22 17:35:06Z","state":"3972be93-8884-4dac-e0b3-59d861f49d56"}}

I don't want to use GUID. Does anyone know how to create only one oauth2 server for all the backend apis?

Before invoking in Developer portal, try it in Test tab of APIM instance. If you get this error then click on Trace to know more about this error

I did that already but it gives the same response. I am following this link to setup oauth2 server https://azure.github.io/apim-lab/apim-lab/7-security/security-7-2-3-oauth2-authorization-grant-flow.html

Have you checked in Trace? You can see specific error message

On error
validate-jwt (-0.236 ms)
{
"message": "JWT Validation Failed: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'api://client_app_id'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'null' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'audience_1, client_app_id"
}

Yes you need to use the correct audience while generating the token

They are same :) Can there be any other missing configuration?

check the audience in validate-jwt policy and in oauth2 authorization

Share the validate-jwt policy and screenshot of oauth authorization configuration

refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78857200/api-management-oauth-2-0-configuration-issue/78860436#78860436

I have added screen shots in the questions

Use default scope as api://{clientId}/.default and I see you are using two audiences

I am using api://{clientId}/user_impersonation. is this not correct? would not it be requesting  token for itself

It will but you need add user_impersonation as scope and use one audience (client id) in validate-jwt policy

I can not use only one audience because I have a existing backend app and it has already its audience. I have registered new client app for oauth2 server and done the steps from here https://azure.github.io/apim-lab/apim-lab/7-security/security-7-2-3-oauth2-authorization-grant-flow.html I just want to allow client app to impersonate users towards backend API

You need to link the backend app to the frontend app as given in the link https://azure.github.io/apim-lab/apim-lab/7-security/security-7-2-3-oauth2-authorization-grant-flow.html

Yes I have added client app id into backend app  Expose an API -> Add Client application and in client app API permissions -> Add a permissions. I have completed all the steps given in the link.

Are you getting any error now? check in trace

Yes the error I had posted before.

Change the default scope to api://client ID/.default and add client app's client ID in audience of validate jwt policy

I decoded the token and I see the aad is client app id. I was assuming that client app will forward impersonate users to a backend app.


Follow each steps given in this Lab clearly, create two multi tenant apps as mentioned in the link.
Create a scope in backend app and then add frontend app in Add a client application. By doing this, you don't need to pass the audiences of both the apps in validate-jwt policy instead you will access the backend app via frontend app.



Grant permission to the backend app in frontend app.



Enable OAuth 2.0 in Azure APIM and provide all the frontend app details. Specify default scope as {frontend app's client id}/.default.




Add the given policy in your API.

<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>{Frontend App ClientID}</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/{tenantID}/</issuer>
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
</policies>


Link the OAuth 2.0 to the API by navigating to API -> Settings and then, publish the changes to the developer portal. When you will choose Authorization flow as authorization_code in developer portal, you should below pop up.




You will get expected 200 OK response.



I have posted another question do you know how to do this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78893854/how-to-create-secret-in-client-app-in-azure

Do I have to add client app id to backend app -> Expose an API -> Authorized client applications?

@Panda Yes, you need to add Authorized client applications in backend app

Okay! now I have added audience as you has shown in the  answer but in audience validation it fails because it can not find client app id. But i have added it along with other audiences.   {         "code": 401,         "message": "IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '62*****-****-****-****-*****2ee'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'ed****-****-****-****-7****008' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'api:\/\/**-*****dev'."     }

@Panda Are you using the client id of frontend app in validate jwt policy and client of frontend app/.default in oauth? It looks like you are passing incorrect audience. in the error message audiences are different

Yes i have added client id of frontend app in validate jwt policy. I can not use .default because i have added different backend apps in api permission of frontend client app

Can you try once using .default?

When I use .default {"code":"Unauthorized","message":{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90009: Application '81***----*******85' is requesting a token for itself. This scenario is supported only if resource is specified using the GUID based App Identifier.}

I have updated a question, hope it gives more idea about the setup I have
